# React Native iOS ImageBackground resizeMode: 'repeat' is scaling the image. Works fine on Android

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, image-resizing, imagebackground

I am trying to add image border to my Flatlist items. For that purpose I am using Imagebackground component. But, on iOS, ImageBackground resizeMode: 'repeat' is scaling/stretching the image. It works fine on Android. [Here](https://snack.expo.dev/@rabiarashid/frowning-sandwich?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=performancemax&gclid=CjwKCAjwx_eiBhBGEiwA15gLNygGw-aylLRIWlpSACaROCmbMBlYT2NM_mmygfEgwG8tyE_ypsj-8hoCoFgQAvD_BwE) is the snack link. Attached are the reference images. How to make it just like the android view i.e. the border should be fine/thin not scaled?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
  const chapters = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];
  itemKeyExtractor = (item) => item.id;

  const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={require('./assets/border.jpg')}
        style={{
          padding: 10,
          marginVertical: 10,
          width: 'auto',
          height: 'auto',
        }}
        imageStyle={{ resizeMode: 'repeat'}}
        resizeMode="repeat">
        <View style={styles.item}>
        <Text> {item.id}</Text>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={chapters}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={itemKeyExtractor}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 100,
    padding: 10,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

[image: iOS][image: android]

Comment: Did you get to resolve it?

Comment: @marcelofreires no

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you figure out the image's right crop to make a patterned border. I did it on this [Snack Expo example](https://snack.expo.dev/@marcelofreires/stackoverflow-questions-76239942) for you. This is the nearest border pattern between iOS and Android.

Comment: @artsnr, did you try this? Look at the code and new asset called `border-pattern.jpg`

Comment: thanks for your input. Yes, I viewed you snack and I can see both android and iOS look alike now but the problem is that I want the android pattern (the delicate one) on iOS, not the iOS pattern (the broad and scaled one) on android.